# Subtract minutes from a date column based on a value in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to subtract minutes from a date column based on the value in another table. But query is getting into error.  Can someone advise on this?

```
TABLE 1 NAME - MYTABLE1 

COLUMN NAME "IN_DATE" Data type - DATE

TABLE 2
NAME - CONFIG_TABLE
COLUMN NAME - PARAM_NAME VALUE = SUBTRACT_MINUTE_VALUE
COLUMN NAME   PARAM_VALUE  VALUE =15

SELECT IN_DATE , IN_DATE - interval (SELECT PARAM_VALUE FROM CONFIG_TABLE WHERE PARAM_NAME='SUBTRACT_MINUTE_VALUE') minute FROM MYTABLE1
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I do it: subtract minutes as *number of minutes divided by (24 hours (in a day) x 60 minutes (in an hour))*

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.

SQL> create table config (subtract_minute_value number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into config values (15);

1 row created.

SQL> create table mytable1 (in_date date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into mytable1 values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select m.in_date, m.in_date - c.subtract_minute_value / (24 * 60) result
  2  from mytable1 m, config c;

IN_DATE          RESULT
---------------- ----------------
02.02.2018 06:56 02.02.2018 06:41

SQL>
```

**[EDIT based on Aleksej's ANSI JOIN suggestion, along with NUMTODSINTERVAL option]**

```
SQL> select m.in_date,
  2         m.in_date - c.subtract_minute_value / (24 * 60) result
  3  from mytable1 m join config c on 1 = 1;

IN_DATE          RESULT
---------------- ----------------
02.02.2018 07:51 02.02.2018 07:36

SQL>
SQL> select m.in_date,
  2         m.in_date - numtodsinterval(c.subtract_minute_value, 'minute') result
  3  from mytable1 m join config c on 1 = 1;

IN_DATE          RESULT
---------------- ----------------
02.02.2018 07:51 02.02.2018 07:36

SQL>
```

Comment: It would be better to show a solution in ANSI SQL, avoiding the old Oracle style

Comment: @Aleksej, is it a *JOIN* you're talking about? If so, OK - thanks, I added that option, along with yet another NUMTODSINTERVAL way to get the result. If not, hm, what then? Though, what's wrong with the "Old" Oracle style - **In this case**, it is really a simple one while ANSI looks ... worse :)

Comment: The join, nothing else :)

Comment: OK then, fixed!

Comment: I admire and follow your enthuiasm, you overtook me less than two months period :) congratulations!

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use an `interval` of one minute and multiply that with the number stored in the config table.

```
select m.in_date,
       m.in_date - (interval '1' minute * c.param_value) as result
from mytable1 m 
  cross join config_table c on c.param_name = 'SUBTRACT_MINUTE_VALUE'
```

Comment: `interval '1' minute * c.param_value` Now that's smart!

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this,

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM';

SELECT SYSDATE current_time, 
       SYSDATE - (1/24/60)*:p_min current_time_minus_mins
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: What is the reason for `TO_CHAR()`?

Comment: To display the date in 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM' format. If I put SYSDATE, it will only display in DD-MON-YYYY format (in my end).

Comment: Then you should change your session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting